# Element height/width scaling issue

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with a background element. I have two divs, curtain_left and curtain_right that need to be 100% of the height of the browser, no less than 20% width and no more than 40% width. The main requirement is that the curtain scale to 100% of the height.

Right now, I have

```
#curtain_left {
left: 0px;
min-width: 20%;
max-width:40%
height: 100%;
text-align: left;
z-index: -1;
position: fixed;
background-image: url(img/curtain_right.png);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

It seems to be only paying attention to the min-width, and not expanding based on the scaled height. So it works on wide-screen monitors, but on standard, the background image will expand to the 20% width and then leave an awkward spacing on the bottom.

[image]

Any tips?

http://jsfiddle.net/kJbcj/1/

Comment: please set-up an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ that also contains your web markup

Comment: Okay, done: http://jsfiddle.net/kJbcj/1/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: removed the jquery solution.**

I understood you wrong hence posted that, well it would be better if you try providing height and max-height to 100% to that element along with all the parent elements. For example

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="curtain_left"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .wrapper, #curtain_left {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Please give a try with this concept.

Comment: I'm just trying to make the background-image of the curtain div scale to 100% of the page height, and have the width scale appropriately (adjusting to the scaled width of the background-image). On some monitors this means 100% height and 20% width, on some it means 100% height and 40% width. I don't think the jquery solution would help me with that, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Didn't solve it. The actual element is stretching to 100% height- that's not the problem. The problem is that the width is sticking to the minimum-width and not scaling to the background image.
For example, the element height is 100%, the width is sticking to 20%, and the background-image is just scaling to the width, so the image isn't filling the entire 100%. What I need is for the image to scale to the height and then the width to scale accordingly instead of just staying at 100% and forcing the image to scale to the width. Sorry for being overly verbose.